# What was the song Kousei played after "Twinkle, Twinkle, Little Star" in episode 3?

Tags: music, your-lie-in-april

In episode 3, Kousei and a little kid play the happy piano, playing "Twinkle, Twinkle, Little Star". Kousei then changes the tune.

Was what he played a real piece of music? And if so, what was it called?

Comment: It's still the same piece -_-

Comment: This is called improvisation, and as @Gao wrote it's still the same piece.

Comment: Not so much an improvisation @Chinatsu-creepy-chan as an actual passage from *[Twinkle, Twinkle Little Star](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOXdAa-G4bo&t=48s)*.

Comment: @Gao yup, improvisation from the music xD. I'm a pianist and I've already done this kind of improvisation. Given the harmonic field and music's progression, you choose some part of the music and change it's melody. ^_^

Comment: @Chinatsu-creepy-chan you should add this as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Mozart's Twelve Variations on 'Ah, vous dirai-je maman' (Twinkle Twinkle Little Star).

[Listen to it on Youtube.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BTvoqVK420)